# Jquery swf in full screen background (width and heigth 100%)

Tags: jquery, flash

I'd like to use my swf animation (500x350) as full screen background in my site (height and width 100%). It is possible? Is there a plug-in to do this? How otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it needs more than just a plugin. One simple way is to make your flash scaleable and embed it with 100% width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but it's a bit of quirky at best.
First of all, since Flash is topMost by default, you need to play around with the wmode and several flashsettings (more info here: http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/54-flash-on-top-of-the-html-elements-changing-the-window-mode-parameter.html )

And after that you need to mess around with the z-index etc; see here: http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_flashbackground.html

Comment: I haven't seen where I can set swf to strech 100% width and hight